# Exercise on graphing integral of floor function

Tags: calculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

My question is from Apostol's Vol. 1: One-variable calculus with introduction to linear algebra textbook.

> *Page 70. Exercise 6.*
>
> a) If $n$ is a positive integer, prove that $\int_0^n\lfloor t\rfloor^2\mathrm dt=\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}.$
>
> b) If $f(x)=\int_0^x\lfloor t\rfloor^2\mathrm dt$ for $x\ge0$, draw the graph of $f$ over the interval $[0,3]$.
>
> c) Find all $x>0$ for which $\int_0^x\lfloor t\rfloor^2\mathrm dt=2(x-1)$.

*The attempt at a solution.* I solved a), and I think my solution is correct, here it is:

We know that $$\int_0^n\lfloor t\rfloor^2\mathrm dt=1^2+2^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2$$ and $$1^2+2^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2=\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}$$ therefore $$\int_0^n\lfloor t\rfloor^2\mathrm dt=\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}.$$

For b), I am confused, I thought I should have graphed $f(x)=\frac{2x^3-3x^2+x}{6}=\frac{x(x-1)(2x-1)}{6}$, but that's silly, because the formula is for $\int_0^n\lfloor t\rfloor^2\mathrm dt$ where $n$ is integer. So I guess $f(x)=\int_0^x\lfloor t\rfloor^2\mathrm dt$ from $0$ to $3$ would be constant $5$, since $\int_0^3\lfloor t\rfloor^2\mathrm dt=5$, am I correct?

As for c), my attempt was to solve this equation: $$\frac{x(x-1)(2x-1)}{6}=2(x-1)$$ $$x=\frac{1}{4}(1-\sqrt{97}), x=\frac{1}{4}(1+\sqrt{97}).$$ This is not correct. So any hints would be appreciated on b) and c). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b): You're not right in saying that $f(x)$ is constant. You know the value in $0, 1, 2$ and $3$ (from the formula you proved in a), try to think about what happens to $\lfloor t\rfloor^2$ between two integers and use that to find out how $f$ behaves on those intervals.

c) should be easy when you've figured out how $f$ behaves on the intervals between the integers.

Comment: I followed your advice, and graphed $f(x)=\int_0^x\lfloor t\rfloor^2\mathrm dt$ from $0$ to $3$, it would look like this: http://i.imgur.com/8yFzmqt.jpg, can you confirm if it's true?

Comment: That looks right. As the integrand is piecewise constant, the integral should be piecewise linear.

Comment: It is a piecewise linear function as you said, for c), I found the easy one, for which $f(x)=2(x-1)$, it would be $x=1$, but since function doesn't have a single formula, which I would make equal to $2(x-1)$ and solve for $x$, how do I find other points?

Comment: Either you set each of them (there are only three) equal to $2(x-1))$, or you find some other way of determining which has a chance of giving a solution. Note that there might be a solution for more than one segment.

Comment: I think I constructed formula for the function: $$f(x)=\int_0^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\lfloor t\rfloor^2\mathrm dt+\lfloor x\rfloor^2(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)$$ which I will try to equate to $2(x-1)$, I don't know how it will work though.

Comment: It actually works, yay! Here's the graph from 0 to 5: http://i.imgur.com/E5l3pcG.png but I don't know how to solve it so that it gives me those $x$'s for which $f(x)=2(x-1)$.

Comment: Nevermind, I got the answer from here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066305/how-do-i-solve-floor-function-integral-equation, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this problem.

The integral is equal to $$x\lfloor{x}\rfloor^{2} + \frac{\lfloor x-1 \rfloor (\lfloor x-1 \rfloor + 1) (2 \lfloor x-1 \rfloor + 1)}{6} - \lfloor x \rfloor ^3 $$
Equating this equation to $2(x - 1)$ we get an equation for $x$ in terms of $\lfloor x \rfloor$.
$$x = \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor^3 - \frac{\lfloor x-1 \rfloor (\lfloor x-1 \rfloor + 1) (2 \lfloor x-1 \rfloor + 1)}{6} - 2}{\lfloor x \rfloor^2 - 2} $$
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duN74.png) - the blue curve is for $2(x-1) and the red one is for the integral.

From the above graph, it's quite evident that the intersection takes place at $x = 1$ and somewhere between $x = 2$ and $x = 3$.

Notice that $\lfloor x \rfloor = 2$ for all $2 \le x \lt 3$. Substituting $\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$ in the equation for $x$, we get $x = 1$ and substituting $\lfloor x \rfloor = 2$, we get $x = \frac{5}{2}$. (using $\lfloor x-1 \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor - 1$).

Hope this helps.